# Subscription payment window does not launch when trying to buy a subscription

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, subscription

I am using the below library.
In-app products work fine in this library, but when I click on subscriptions, nothing happens. What do you think is the problem?

Lib : https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/main/TrivialDriveJava

Example issue; https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/465

Comment: check your logs after click `Log.e("TAG","sku is === " + sku);` for this line

Comment: When I click the subscription button, it gives no logs. no reaction